# NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector: crash

Tags: objective-c, crash, block

Crash report:

```
    0  CoreFoundation!__exceptionPreprocess + 0x7c
    1  libobjc.A.dylib!objc_exception_throw + 0x34
    2  CoreFoundation!-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 0xd0
    3  CoreFoundation!___forwarding___ + 0x364[enter image description here][1]
    4  CoreFoundation!_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 0x58
    5  yyfe!__70-[InvestModel getOpenAccountRewardWithPhoneNum:identifyCode:complete:]_block_invoke [InvestModel.m : 104 + 0x4]
    6  libdispatch.dylib!_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 0x14
    7  libdispatch.dylib!_dispatch_client_callout + 0xc
    8  libdispatch.dylib!_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 0x730
    9  CoreFoundation!__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 0x8
```

my code:

```
    NSDictionary* data = returnDict[@"data"];
    NSInteger respStatus = [data[@"respStatus"] integerValue];

    if ([data[@"code"] isEqual: @(1)] && respStatus == 6) {
        [weakSelf saveSuccessGetOpenAccountReward];
        callback(YES,[data[@"rank"] integerValue],[data[@"amount"] integerValue],getRewardSuccess);
        return;
    }
```

and callback type:

```
    typedef void(^GetRewardCallBack)(BOOL,NSInteger,NSInteger,GetRewardMessageType);
```

104 line is callback(), returnDict has value for "rank" and "amount", I not sure if callback = nil make crash, but callback can not equal nil, any idea?

Comment: if you go step by step, at which line do you get crash?

Comment: What is the exception text? (the text that tells you what object and what selector are the cause).

Comment: Crash log was from my Crash System, my user found this crash. It doesn't crash when I connect and debug with Xcode.

Comment: All I got is the crash log on the top.

Comment: Did you make sure that the code base used by client is the same as yours? Just want to make sure the crashed line is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out! data[@"rank"],returned by server, is neither a NSString nor a NSNumber. So it can't recognize @selector(integerValue)